# Facades Laravel Calling Library directly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How do i call it without library without the "facades" on laravel 5

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

```
PDF::loadHTML($html)->setPaper('a4')->setOrientation('landscape')->setWarnings(false)->save('myfile.pdf')

return PDF::loadFile(public_path().'/myfile.html')->save('/path-to/my_stored_file.pdf')->stream('download.pdf');
```

I tried this failed badly. Class not found

```
    $library = new \barryvdh\laraveldompdf\src\getDomPDF();
    $pdf = $library->loadView('welcome', '');
    return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

php is case sensitive, so you need to provide the namespace with capital letters if they are set like this.

```
$lib = new \Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF();
```

should work.

I'm not sure what you have done in the first two lines of code you posted, but you will need to

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF;
```

right after the namespace declaration in the file you wish to use the code.

Comment: getting Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF' not found

Comment: @CodeGuru When used in the code, FQCNs must be prefixed with the backslash: `$lib = new \Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF();`. When used with the `use` statement, they should not be prefixed: `use Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF; $lib = new PDF();`